# Linking 'Enter' key to button - not working

Tags: jquery, html, button, onkeyup

I'm using some jQuery to link the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to an HTML button using the following code:

```
$("#console").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#submit").click();
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="console" placeholder="/help, /attack, /heal, /flee" autofocus></input>

<input type="submit" onclick="play()" id="submit" value="Enter"></input>
```

For some reason, it's not working for me right now. There's no error message, it seems like the jQuery doesn't even run.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to replace `event` with something?

Comment: Is this HTML code within a form element?

Comment: Not sure, but will an elemt in the page catch keyboard events unless clicked first?, try $(document).on('keyup','#submit', function(){...});

Comment: If you read my HTML, the page autofocuses on the textbox upon load, thanks to the `autofocus` attribute.  Also, the Enter key should only be linked when focused the console, so how would other elements catch the event?

Comment: @mr12086 Your code doesn't work either.

Comment: @DominatorX maybe it's a timing issue in your code, your edited code [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/trmg1zsr/).

Comment: To test if jquery is loaded you can run `jQuery.fn.jquery` in the console and it will either tell you the version or throw an error.

Comment: @jcuenod It currently tells me the version. (2.1.3) So jQuery is loaded then...

Comment: Can I recommend that you revert your question to be asking what the answers below are trying to answer and then post a new question. It will be helpful to list any errors in the console and any js files you are using (especially your own) but do this in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Err... a beginner's mistake...

I forgot to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Nothing provoked the code to run in the first place so it never worked. Noticed it in Teemu's fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#enter").click();` selects elements with the `id` "enter". It seems you're hoping to select your submit button but it has the id `submit` so try using `$("#submit").click();`

```js
$("#console").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#submit").click();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="console"autofocus></input>
<input type="button" onclick="alert('hurray')" value="enter" id="submit"></input>
```

See:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
and I also just discovered this which looks pretty helpful: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: Hm... I referenced `jquery.js` from a different source: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`.  Might that be a problem?

Comment: Well just try the url I've used but the simple thing to do is visit point your browser to the url you are referencing (which I've done and it works). So that's not the problem. You're going to have to be more specific than "it isn't working". Have you tried "run code snippet"? It works for me.

Comment: Same, your code works.  I don't know why it wouldn't work in my code :\

Comment: It's not helpful to update your question like this because now the answers don't make sense. Rather ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

'#' means id, here is reference http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

if you want to use id, try this, http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

```
$("#submit").click();
```

if you want to use value='Enter', try this,

```
$("input[value='Enter']").click();
```

Try this JS code. Also you can find demo in [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/5r7wtntq/) as well.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    alert('Enter clicked!');
});

$("#console").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#submit").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Same comment with jcuenod, I've changed it but it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Could you please try again? Thanks.

Comment: My other scripts are interfering with the `alert`, but I removed them.  Now it doesn't even show the alert.  So it's an issue with my HTML?

Comment: ok, could you please re-typing your code in 'plain text' editor, e.g. notepad++ or notepad. maybe there is some special hidden characters in your existing code.

Comment: What do you mean by a "plain text editor"?  I copied and pasted it into Notepad and there are no special symbols.  I typed my code by hand anyways.